# Adding new objects to arrayList isnt working

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public abstract class Bee {
    static Hive hive = Garden.hive;
    protected int type;
    protected int age;
    protected int health = 3;

    protected int getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    protected int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    protected int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    protected void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    protected void setType(int input)
    {
        this.type = input;
    }
    protected abstract boolean eat();
    protected abstract void anotherDay();  //the bees tasks for day (should include eat())

}


    public class Queen extends Bee {

    protected Queen()
    {
        setType(1);
    }
    protected int eggTimer = 0; // tracks when to add a new egg (not using age incase an external factor causes layEgg) 

    // removed code to avoid being too long 

    protected void layEgg() {
        Egg egg = new Egg();
        hive.addBee(egg); //fix??
        eggTimer = 0;
    }
}



        import java.util.ArrayList;

    class Hive {


        ArrayList<Bee> beeList = new ArrayList<Bee>();
        // code removed
        public int beeIndex; // used to know what the index of bee you are in is


        protected void addBee(Bee bee) { //Its running this and getting into the beelist.add(bee) but after there is nothing new in beeList.
            if (beeList.size() < 100) {
                beeList.add(bee);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Too many Bees to add more");
            }
        }

        // removed code to avoid being too long 

        protected void anotherDay() {
            int i = 0;
            for (Bee bee : beeList) {
                i++;
                bee.anotherDay();
                beeIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code runs with no errors but when it gets to layEgg method its ment to add a egg (another class that extends bee) to the arrayList in Hive. It runs and the addBee method and goes over the beeList.add but it isnt adding the object still. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I cut out some of the code to make the post shorter layEgg is ran when anotherDay() is called a 3rd time in Queen.

```
public class Garden {
    static Hive hive = new Hive();
    protected int flowerIndex;
    ArrayList<Flower> flowerList = new ArrayList<Flower>();

    protected void anotherDay() {
        int i = 0;
        for (Flower flower : flowerList) {
            i++;
            flower.anotherDay();
            flowerIndex = i;
        }
    }

    protected void addHive(Hive hiveInput) {
        Hive hive = hiveInput;
    }

    protected void addFlower(Flower flowerInput) {
        Flower flower = flowerInput;
    }

    protected Flower getFlower(int input) {
        return flowerList.get(input);
    }

    protected Flower findFlower() // finds the size of the arrayList and then
                                    // creates a random number within the array
                                    // to use as an index
    {

        int listSize = flowerList.size();
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(listSize);
        return flowerList.get(index);
    }

    protected int getFlowerListSize()
    {
        return flowerList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely it is adding the Bee, but your test is broken. Can you provide an example of what you are doing and what is failing?

Comment: how do you know its not added? are you using same Hive object to print the Bee?

Comment: Im trying to add a new object to an arrayList in Hive, the object is created in Queen and passed as a parameter to Hive and I found it isnt actually adding new objects when i went through with break points.(not sure what you ment by an example hope that answers it)

Comment: Garden is a class that contains Hive but doesnt do anything to it yet (none of its methods are called). I know it hasnt added as it isnt in the arrayList after the add when i go through with breakpoints debugging

Comment: To me, you posted a lot of irrelevant code and left out the relevant stuff.  What is the relationship of `Bee` and `Egg`??  I suggest posting ALL code associated with any list and leave out methods that don't reference any of the lists, if you want to make it smaller.  , I can assure you that adding things to a List is NOT broken in Java.  You are either adding things to a different list, getting things from a different list, or removing the items somewhere after they have been added.

Comment: As a side note, `replaceBee(...)` is far less efficient than it should be (...er...); you should use `.set(index, addBee)`.  Other stuff - try not to use types as part of variable names (use `bees` instead of `beeList`).  Try not to use mutable static variables, and remove all unused/unreferenced variables whenever possible.  You're doubling up on 'type' information - one from the class structure, the other from an instance variable; pick one (personally, I'd pick a variation of the instance variable with an enum... or other changes; inheritance gets ugly fast)

Comment: Thanks for the .set advice and i didnt post egg as it just containts anotherday that adds age so doesnt effect anything else than itself, I wasnt sure what code was exactly relivant and just to avoid the confusion i wasnt trying to say the ArrayList.add() was broken just was confused as to what i had done that stopped it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check (using breakpoints, or debug statements, or both).

- Is everything pointing to the same Hive object
- Is everything pointing to the same List object

I can guarantee that adding stuff to Lists in Java works - so your code is either:

- Not adding the stuff
- Adding the stuff to the wrong list
- Removing it from the list after adding

Just check for all those cases and narrow things down until you find the cause.

Comment: Seems to be adding it to a different Queen is in id21 and egg is in id40 seems odd as i didnt think i was creating more than 1 beeList as when Hive is created as a static

Comment: Does this mean the problem is in Bee with static Hive hive = Garden.hive; or is the extra arrayList likey to be elsewhere?

Comment: One of the first rules of debugging - check you assumptions :) I don't know which the problem is, as it is your code and I can't see enough of that. (And don't have time to debug your code for free either ;) ). All I can say is you are setting up or passing around something wrongly. Try logging every time the list may be created and see what is going on. You can do new Exception().printStackTrace() to get a stack trace for any point of code for example.